# Taxonomy terms with a scale?

Tags: 7

Not quite sure how I should even google this. I've got a Content Type "Trips", the image shows what I want to see in my trips node page. Adventurus, relaxing, educational etc are my taxonomy term categories. It seems to me like each taxonomy term should have a scale of 0-5. Which is the better way to achieve this? Any module around? (using drupal 7)[image]

Comment: Sounds like a combination of taxonomy and the https://drupal.org/project/fivestar module

Comment: Thanks alot, that's a nice solution and as far as I can see it's easy to customize the graphics.

Answer (score 0):

I used [Star Rating module](https://drupal.org/project/starrating). Exactly what I was looking for. In contrast with [Fivestar module](https://drupal.org/project/fivestar), it is intended for rating only by the author of the node. Plus no dependencies.
[Thanks to @jimajamma]

Answer (score 0):

In drupal 7, you can add fields to taxonomies. Use the following steps:

1. Install the [star rating formatter](https://drupal.org/project/starrating) mentioned by @Nim, then configure
2. Can two posts have a different # of categories?

   - If so, I suggest you add such a single star rating formatter field to the desired taxonomy (http://example.com/admin/structure/taxonomy//fields). Make sure the field and the taxonomy are multi-valued.
   - If not, consider adding three separate taxonomy fields.

Amnon